# struts didn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

I have a form and I set the action pf to /translate

```
<form name="frm" action="/translate">
...
</form>
```

and map the /translate URL in struts-config.xml like this:

```
    <action-mappings>
    <action name="TranslatorBean" path="/translate" scope="request" type="com.myapp.struts.TranslateCtrl" validate="false">
        <forward name="success" path="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

but when I submit the form I get 404 error!!

Comment: Which part is not working? invoking controller (or) forwarding to jsp? I strongly suspect it is forwarding to jsp, contoller might getting called properly. Add some debugging in controller and make sure which layer failing.

Comment: Now, next question would be where is /welcomeStruts.jsp? is it under WEB-INF or outside WEB-INF? Try to give full jsp path there and see.

Comment: @D3GAN - please post your web.xml

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<form name="frm" action="/translate.do">
```

instead

Regards

Comment: It didn't work.
I see this kind of mapping in the Netbeans IDE tutorials :
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-struts.html#success
I did it step by step but it didn't work!!

Comment: Action controller is being invoked properly, so it is not controller mapping issue. It is related to .jsp mapping. I strongly suspect JSP is not avaiable from relative path.

Comment: I put a printf in the controller (execute method) but I can't see it when I ran the application.